# Reference firestore database with firebase auth uID

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to reference Auth uID with my created users DB through firebase console? Or i need to do it through application by writing code?

Since my app doesn't have registration but only log in as a function, then i have already populated auth table, but i need to somehow reference each uID with user in DB.

One way that i thought about was that i would create new users DB field when someone logs in for the first time. That could be a workaround, but still.

Maybe someone has an idea or solution of what i should do to achieve a result for my problem?

Comment: So you authenticate users in Firebase only using email and password, right?

Comment: Yes, that's the way i chose.

Comment: Have you simply trried to login and get the the `uid` of the user from the `FirebaseUser` object? Does it work that way?

Comment: I have not tried anything with code, because im currently just planing structure.